# In Windows 10 is it possible to arrange virtual desktops in a grid with multiple rows and columns as I can on linux?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Title says it all.  I usually have a 3x4 array of virtual desktops on linux.  Can I do the same on Windows 10.

I don't believe that you can with the UI.  Was wondering if it were possible by editing the registry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @demented hedgehog answer, [VirtualDesktopGridSwitcher](https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtual-desktop-grid-switcher/) will work out for Windows 10. I managed to get the last version (2.4.0.0 at the time of writing) to work on Windows 10 (Version 10.0.17134 **Build 17134**).

The application is not very configurable for now, so does not allow customized key bindings for desktop switch, move windows, etc. But alternative alias key bindings can be achieved using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) with a minimal little script of aliases. I paste my key-binding alias script at the end, which is based on VIM motion (j,k,h,l) to switch desktops/move windows.

The application default icons are based on a 3x3 grid layout, so if you require a different layout you would probably prefer to change those default icon set with something from here: https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/?page_id=48 (I use a 2x2 grid, so icons are available) or you could provide your own icons. Just need to place the icons into the application `Icons` folder and name it from `1.ico` to `n.ico`.

**Regarding that, it is usable and works!** It could be improved but it solves the problem of desktop layout and desktop switching/window moving using strictly the keyboard.

```
; AutoHotKey script

; Uncomment the next line if you don't want this script appearing in your system tray
;#NoTrayIcon

; Read this for more details and keys:
; https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

; Switch desktop aliases (using Ctrl-Alt + VIM motion key)

^!l::^!Right
^!h::^!Left
^!j::^!Down
^!k::^!Up

; Move window aliases (using AltGr + key)

<^>!l::^!+Right
<^>!h::^!+Left
<^>!j::^!+Down
<^>!k::^!+Up
<^>!Right::^!+Right
<^>!Left::^!+Left
<^>!Down::^!+Down
<^>!Up::^!+Up
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way.

Windows 10 Desktop Switcher using a grid layout
Switch desktops using arrow keys with configurable modifier keys

https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtual-desktop-grid-switcher/

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 now has a similar option called
[Task View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_View),
which is both a task switcher and a virtual desktop manager.

You may use it to bring a window to the foreground, but also to view the available
virtual desktops, bring one forward, add a new one or remove.

The virtual desktops are arranged at the top with their screen-image,
and you may click to choose:

[image]

More information can be found in the articles:

- [How to use Task View features on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-task-view-windows-10)
- [Get to the task with Windows 10’s Task View and Aero Snap](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-use-task-view-and-aero-snap-in-windows-10/)
- [How to Turn Off Task View Timeline in Windows 10](https://www.techjunkie.com/turn-off-task-view-timeline-windows-10/)

Comment: Pro: native functionality; smooth animations. Con: Doesn't seem to allow vertically-arranged virtual desktops, which is the main point of the question.

Comment: That's Microsoft's solution. If you are looking at third-party products, perhaps the old [Dexpot](https://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en) still works. But most of these products are no longer developed for Windows 10, since Microsoft has added its own native solution.

Comment: Interesting .. but it's not what I'm looking for.  I don't want to go looking for apps in a list.  The workflow I want is to know where apps are spatialy in 2D.  I always have the same apps running in the same locations and I usually have a lot of apps open (and keep them open for weeks at a time).  I want to organize it like my tool shed.. everything has a place and I know where that is.  Organizing in 1D  gets too long to manage easily.

Answer (score 1):

VirtuaWin (virtuawin.sourceforge.io) - Been using it for 10 years on Win 7 and Win 10. 2d layout of desktops. I'm a 2x2 guy myself. Friendly, customizable, all good.

Unfortunately, my IT department does not see this as something I'm allowed to use anymore (company is getting too big). I just discovered the W10 desktop manager, which *might* work... probably the biggest deal is that it gives you no idea what desktop you are on unless you are in "Task View"... VirtuaWin gives you a MxN prompt in the notifications area...